# eBay Trading API - How to get shipping label for an order to be shipped?

Tags: ebay-api

I am able to get the orders for a seller through eBay `GetSellerList` (Trading API) and `GetOrders` (Fulfillment API) calls. I also found an API
`CompleteSale` for processing the orders but could not find any API for generating the shipping label like [this sample Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmdwE.png).

Any help is appreciated.
TIA

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/post-order/index.html

Comment: @František Žiačik thanks for the reply but the post order API is for cancel  and return orders   , what I want is APIs or methods to generate the shipping label , order statement (invoice) and manifest for an order which is not processed yet.

Comment: @PiyushKumar Were you able to get shippingLabels for unprocessed orders?

Comment: @Jobs No I have not found any api for labels either. I was trying there new rest api but that gives empty response